# python, split dictionary into list of tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

```
dictionary = {1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['a'], 3: ['b', 'c']}
```

I want this dictionary to be in list of tuple like this:
output:

```
[(1, 'a'),(1, 'b'),(2, 'a'),(3, 'b'),(3, 'c')]
```

Please help me out in this!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a comprehension:

```
[(x, z) for x, y in dictionary.items() for z in y]
```

Or expanded out:

```
out = []
for x, y in dictionary.items():
    for z in y:
        out.append((x, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

dictionary = {1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['a'], 3: ['b', 'c']}

```
list_of_tuples = []
for k,v_list in dictionary.items():
    for v in v_list:
        list_of_tuples.append((k,v))
list_of_tuples
```

Comment: This doesn't 'unpack' the list values into new tuples.